# Data from database is not fetched/displayed in listview flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, listview

I have a screen which shows list of customers using listview. Next when I click on a customer I want to show the notes(records) only of that particular customer(customerId) in next screen in listview. This is my code which should work fine but its not displaying anything. I have checked if noteDetails table contains data and it has. Can anyone tell where am I wrong or what code should i add more please.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/screens/user_login.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
Map<int, Color> color ={50:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95,  .1),
  100:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .2),
  200:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .3),
  300:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .4),
  400:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .5),
  500:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .6),
  600:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .7),
  700:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .8),
  800:Color.fromRGBO(170, 0, 95, .9),
  900:Color.fromRGBO(170,0,95, 1),};
MaterialColor colorCustom = MaterialColor(0xFF880E4F, color);
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'NoteKeeper',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch:colorCustom,
          primaryColor:colorCustom//primarySwatch: Colors.purple
      ),
      home: UserLogin(),
    );
  }
}
```

Note_info.dart //This is the file where i want to display the notes of particular customer.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:customer/models/CustomerNote.dart';
import 'package:customer/models/addCustomer.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:customer/utils/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'New_Note.dart';


class Note_Info extends StatefulWidget{
  final String appBarTitle;
  final AddCustomer customer;


  Note_Info(this. customer, this.appBarTitle);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return Note_InfoState(this. customer,this.appBarTitle);
  }

}

class Note_InfoState extends State<Note_Info> {
  DBService dbService = DBService();
  List<CustomerNote> noteList;
  int count = 0;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  CustomerNote note=CustomerNote();
  String appBarTitle;
  AddCustomer customer;
  Note_InfoState(this.customer, this.appBarTitle);


 
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController custNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int customerId=customer.custId;
    if (noteList == null) {
      noteList = List<CustomerNote>();
      updateListView();
    }

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    custNameController.text = customer.custName;

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.add,

                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => NewNote(note)));
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(controller: custNameController,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Row(children: [
                        ImageProfile(customer.custPhoto),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.call,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              size: 45,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {

                            },
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: AppBar(
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              text: "All",
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Pending",
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Cancelled",
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Completed",
                             
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // create widgets for each tab bar here
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          // first tab bar view widget
                          Container(
                              child: getNoteListView()
                          ),

                          // second tab bar viiew widget
                          Container(

                          ),


                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Cancelled',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(

                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Completed',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 55.0,
                        width: 200,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 2,

                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          color: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryColorDark,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text('Save', textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              //_reset();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            )
        ));
  }

  Widget ImageProfile(String fileName) {
    return Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage:  fileName == null
              ?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
              :FileImage(File(customer.custPhoto))),

    );

  }


  ListView getNoteListView() {

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(


            title: Text(this.noteList[position].note, style: titleStyle,),
          
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.grey,),
              onTap: () {
               
              },
            ),
            onTap: () {
             
            },

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  void updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = DB.init();
    dbFuture.then((database) {
      int cid=customer.custId;
      Future<List<CustomerNote>> noteListFuture = dbService.getCustomerNotes(cid);
      noteListFuture.then((noteList) {
        setState(() {
          this.noteList = noteList;
          this.count = noteList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }

}
```

New_Note.dart  //This is where new note is added in database successfully

```
import 'package:customer/models/CustomerNote.dart';
import 'package:customer/models/addCustomer.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/Note_info.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:customer/utils/form_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';
import 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewNote extends StatefulWidget{
    final CustomerNote note;
    NewNote(this. note);

   final Function(Color) onChanged;
  final double height;
  final double width;

  NewNote({
    Key key,
    this.onChanged,
    this.height = 25,
    this.width = 150,
    this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);*/
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return New_NoteState(this.note);
  }

}
class New_NoteState extends State<NewNote> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  New_NoteState(this.note);
  CustomerNote note=new CustomerNote();
  AddCustomer customer=new AddCustomer();
  TextEditingController NoteController=TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController custNameController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _reminderDate = DateTime.now();
DBService dbService=new DBService();

SpeedDial _speedDial(){
  return SpeedDial(
    animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.add_event,

    animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 24.0),
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
    curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
    children: [
      SpeedDialChild(
        child: Icon(Icons.location_on,color: Colors.yellow,),
        label: 'Add Location',
      ),
      SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice),
          //backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
          label: 'Add voice',
          //labelBackgroundColor: Colors.yellow

      ),
      SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.attachment_outlined,color :Colors.redAccent),
          label: 'Add File',
      ),
      SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.image,color: Colors.lightBlue,),
          label: 'Add Image',

      ),
    ],
  );
}

  //for DropDownMenu
  Color value=Colors.red;
  final List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.pink,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.brown,
  ];


  bool isSwitched = false;
  var textValue = 'Switch is OFF';

  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {

    if(isSwitched == false)
    {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = true;
        this.note.remindOn = _reminderDate.toString();

      });
    }
    else
    {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = false;
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    custNameController.text = customer.custName;

    return WillPopScope(

      onWillPop: () {
        moveToLastScreen();
      },
child: Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(),
      body:ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 2.0,
        ),
          TextField(controller: custNameController,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text("Add New",textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        ),

      SizedBox(
        height: 2.0,
      ),
      Divider(),
      SizedBox(
        height: 2.0,
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: NoteController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0),)),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          minLines: 5,
          maxLines: 5,
          onChanged: (value) {
            this.note.note = value;
          },

        ),
      ),
      TableCalendar(
        selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
          return isSameDay(_reminderDate, day);
        },
        onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
          setState(() {
            _reminderDate = selectedDay;
          });
        },
              focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
              firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
              lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),),

        SizedBox(
          height: height*0.03,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(//mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Remind me",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:80.0),
              child: Container(
                child: Switch(
                    onChanged: toggleSwitch,
                    value: isSwitched,
                   
              ),
            ),

          ],),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:<Widget>[
              Text("Priority",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
             Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
               child: Container(
                 child: SmoothStarRating(
                  size: height=50.0,
                   allowHalfRating: false,
                   onRated: (value) {
                    this.note.priority=value;
                     print("rating value -> $value");

                   },
            ),
               ),
             )]),
        ),

        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

            Text("Color",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:80.0),
              child: Container(
                child: DropdownButton<Color>(
                value: value,
                
                onChanged: (color) {
                  setState(() => value = color);
                  
                },
                items: colors.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: e,
                      child: Container(
                       width: 60.0,
                        color: e,
                      ),
                  ),
                )
                      .toList(),
          ),
              ),
            ),

          ],),
        ),

          SizedBox(
          height: height*0.08,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 55.0,
            width: 200,
            child: RaisedButton(
              elevation: 2,

              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text('Save',textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _save();
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),



      ],



    ),
 floatingActionButton:_speedDial(),
    ));

  }
  void moveToLastScreen() {
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }

  void _save() async {
    moveToLastScreen();
    note.custId=customer.custId;
    note.date = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now());
    int result;
    if (note.id != null) {  // Case 1: Update operation
      result = await dbService.updateNote(note);
    } else { // Case 2: Insert Operation
      result = await dbService.insertNote(note);
    }

    if (result != 0) {  // Success
      FormHelper.showAlertDialog(context,'Status', 'Note Saved Successfully');
    } else {  // Failure
      FormHelper.showAlertDialog(context,'Status', 'Problem Saving Note');
    }

  }
}
```

db_service.dart

```
 Future<bool> insertCustomer(AddCustomer model) async {
      await DB.init();
      bool isSaved = false;
      if (model != null) {
        int inserted = await DB.insert(AddCustomer.table, model);

        isSaved = inserted == 1 ? true : false;
      }

      return isSaved;
  }
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getCustomerMapList() async {
    await DB.init();
    var result = await DB.query(AddCustomer.table);
    return result;
  }


  Future<List<AddCustomer>> getCustomerList() async {

    var CustomerMapList = await getCustomerMapList(); 
    int count = CustomerMapList.length;

    List<AddCustomer> customerList = List<AddCustomer>();
   
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      customerList.add(AddCustomer.fromMap(CustomerMapList[i]));
    }
    return customerList;
  }
 Future<int> insertNote(CustomerNote note) async {
    await DB.init();
    var result = await DB.insert(CustomerNote.table, note);
    return result;
  }

    Future<List<CustomerNote>> getCustomerNotes(int customer) async {
        await DB.init();
        var res = await DB.rawQuery("noteDetails WHERE custId = '$customer'");
        int count = res.length;
        List<CustomerNote> notelist = List<CustomerNote>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          notelist.add(CustomerNote.fromMap(res[i]));
        }
        return notelist;
      }
```

database_helper.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:customer/models/model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

abstract class DB {
  static Database _db;

  static int get _version => 1;

  static Future<Database> init() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }

    try {
      var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      String _path = p.join(databasesPath, 'Customer.db');
      _db = await openDatabase(_path, version: _version, onCreate: onCreate);
      print('db location:'+_path);

    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
    }
  }

  static void onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE userDetails (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'firstName STRING, '
            'lastName STRING, mobileNum STRING, emailId STRING, address String,'
            'userType STRING,password STRING)');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE customerDetails (custId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'custName STRING, '
            'mobileNum STRING, company STRING, custPhoto STRING, showOnCall bool,'
            'remindOn STRING,location STRING)');
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE noteDetails (noteId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
            'custId STRING, '
            'custName STRING, date STRING, note STRING, remindOn STRING,'
            'priority STRING,status STRING,attachment STRING)');
    await db.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE languagesKnown(custId INTEGER REFERENCES customerDetails(custId),'
        ' languages STRING,PRIMARY KEY(custId))');

    }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query(String table) async =>
      _db.query(table);

  static Future<int> insert(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.insert(table, model.toMap());

  static Future<int> update(String table, Model model) async => await _db
      .update(table, model.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [model.id]);

  static Future<int> delete(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.delete(table, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [model.id]);

  static Future<int> deleteCustomer(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.delete(table, where: 'custId = ?', whereArgs: [model.custId]);

  static Future<Batch> batch() async => _db.batch();

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> rawQuery(String table) async =>
      _db.query(table);


}
```

people_list.dart // This is where list of customers is displayed and by clicking on a listtile i.e customer, Note_info opens

```
import 'package:customer/models/addCustomer.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/Note_info.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/User_Settings.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/add_person.dart';
import 'package:customer/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:customer/utils/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:customer/utils/form_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class People_List extends StatefulWidget{


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return People_ListState();
  }

}

class People_ListState extends State<People_List> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  DBService dbService = DBService();
  List<AddCustomer> customerList;
  int count = 0;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var _isSelectedItemIndex;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
  }

  
  

  Widget _buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    var horizontalTitleAlignment =
    Platform.isIOS ? CrossAxisAlignment.center : CrossAxisAlignment.start;

    return new InkWell(
      onTap: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: horizontalTitleAlignment,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (customerList == null) {
      customerList = List<AddCustomer>();
      updateListView();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        
      ),
      body:getCustomerListView(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          navigateToCustomer(AddCustomer(), 'Add Person');
        },

        child: const Icon(Icons.add),

      ),
      
  }

  ListView getCustomerListView() {

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        var _imageFile=customerList[position].custPhoto;
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: _imageFile==null?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
                :FileImage(File(_imageFile.toString()))),
            title: Text(this.customerList[position].custName, style: titleStyle,),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            onTap: () {
              navigateToDetail(this.customerList[position],'Edit ');
            },

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  
  void navigateToDetail(AddCustomer customer, String title) async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
     return Note_Info(customer, title);
    }));

    if (result == true) {
      updateListView();
    }
  }
 
  void updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = DB.init();
    dbFuture.then((database) {

      Future<List<AddCustomer>> customerListFuture = dbService.getCustomerList();
      customerListFuture.then((customerList) {
        setState(() {
          this.customerList = customerList;
          this.count = customerList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }

 
}
```

Comment: are you able to confirm that you are indeed getting the data where you want it ? Try checking that with print

Comment: where should i add the print statement for that

Comment: After `noteListFuture.then((noteList) {` and before calling `setState`

Comment: Here as well `customerListFuture.then((customerList) {`. Basically wherever you are fetching your data from the databse.

Comment: `noteListFuture.then((noteList) {
        print("list is fetched");
        print(noteList);
        setState(() {
          this.noteList = noteList;
          this.count = noteList.length;
        });  `        I got output as list is fetched [ ]

Comment: Yes, so basically either you dont have any data in the database, or there is some connection mistake and you are unable to fetch the data. That is why it is empty

Comment: Please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: in your code, you calling `DB.init()` multiple times and inside the function you seem to be creating a new database using the onCreate. Ideally there should be only one `DB.init()` call inside your root `main` function. Just call `await DB.init()` there and remove the `DB.init()` calls from all of your code wherever it is

Comment: now when i have added await DB.init() the customer list which used to display previously is also not displaying. :(    `Future<void> updateListView() async {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = (await DB.init()) as Future<Database>;
    dbFuture.then((database) {

      Future<List<CustomerModel>> customerListFuture = dbService.getCustomerList();
      customerListFuture.then((customerList) {
        setState(() {
          this.customerList = customerList;
          this.count = customerList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }`

Comment: You should not need to call DB.init() here again. Only call DB.init() once in `main`, remove it from the rest of the code.

Comment: If I remove DB.init() error says error: The final variable 'dbFuture' must be initialized.

Comment: Have you called `DB.init` in your `main` function ?

Comment: no. u mean in main.dart??? no

Comment: Yes, DB.init should probably be called only once, since that is where all the initialisation will happen. You dont need to initialise and create your tables everytime.

Comment: In my case database is created only once. tables are created only once not everytime. do u have any other suggestion? u can see it in database_helper.dart

Comment: I am not understanding why is my list empty. Customer list is being displayed but the notesList is not displayed. Please help me. I have checked the database. All the data i have entered is saved.

Comment: In `var res = await DB.rawQuery("noteDetails WHERE custId = '$customer'");`, dont you need to give `select` keyword as well ?

Comment: No actually when giving select it says error. It by default takes select from and adds it. so if we write select it becomes double

Comment: count = Sqflite
    .firstIntValue(await database.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test'));
assert(count == 2);

Comment: This is from their examples

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I myself had to solve the problem. The problem was that where I was creating note and saving it in "note" table cust_id was not saved in the table. So I passed CustomerModel object and NoteModel object to New_Note(). Now its working fine

new_note.dart

```
 class NewNote extends StatefulWidget{
      final NoteModel note;
      final CustomerModel customer;
     
      NewNote(this.customer,this. note);
    
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        //return New_NoteState(this.customer);
        return New_NoteState(this.customer,this.note);
      }
class New_NoteState extends State<NewNote> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  New_NoteState(this.customer,this.note);
  NoteModel note=new NoteModel();
  CustomerModel customer=new CustomerModel();
}
void _save() async {
    note.cust_id=customer.cust_id;
...
}
```